# Error Page is taking 25 to 35 % of cpu in Nopcommerce 2.40

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, nopcommerce

I'm using Nopcommerce 2.40.

I've run load test with 5 virtual user for 1 min  on `ErrorPage.htm` which is simple HTML page and found that..It is taking 25 to 35% of CPU.

I think it is going to be serious performance problem if simple HTML is taking too much CPU.There is no need to check other pages and it  does not matter whether you are using Output caching or other caching to improve performance.

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It executes several SQL commands. There is a fix available here:

http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/f693be2bc2e0

This will add htm and html pages to ignore.